# Vue How to set property on a component with parent and in itself? [Warn]

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a component, which I use as a nested component (more level of components) and by a vue-router mounted component also. Sometimes I'm passing the data from the parent, or set it inside the component.

My component:

```
module.exports = {
    props: {
        post: {
            default: Object
        }
    }
    mounted() {
        if( ! this.post.id) {
            this.$http.get('posts/' + this.$route.params.post).then((r) => {

                // This works fine    
                this.post.id = r.data.id

                // This gives warn, to avoid mutate property directly, 
                // because the parent will overwrite it.
                // But here, there is no parent (with post data)!
                // If I set post as data(), also gives a warn cause the props setting
                this.post = r.data

            })
        }
    },
    // other parts...
}
```

**Nested version:**

On the nested way, I'm passing a property to the component, like this:

`<post :post="post"></post>`

**Router version**

Just simply passing the component to the router

`{name : 'post/:post', component: Post}`

How can I set the property **without a warning**? (In the case when I use the component in two different ways) I have a lot of property for a post, so its not so clean to add it one by one. Also I don't want to set on the `<router-view :post="post">` component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is discouraged to **directly** change the parent data from within a child component.

In order to trigger a change, child can just emit an event and then call a parent method using **v-on** directive which then update the data and this updated data flows down to child component and it updates itself automatically.

Read more about One Way data Flow:
https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#One-Way-Data-Flow

```js
// Post component
const post = Vue.component('post', {
  template: '#post-template',
  props: {
    post: {
      default: Object
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    // from child component just emit the change
    // and let parent handle the change
    this.$emit('load-post');
  }
});

// Root Vue Instance
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      post: {
        description: "waiting for post to load..."
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {

    getPost() {
   
      // perform your ajax request here 
      // and update the variable from parent.
  
      self = this;
      setTimeout(function() {
        self.post = {
          description: "this is some random description"
        }
      }, 2000)
    }
  },
  components: {
    post: post
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.0.3/dist/vue.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <post :post="post" v-on:load-post="getPost"></post>
  </div>
</body>

<template id="post-template">
  <div>
    Post: {{ post.description }}
  </div>
</template>
```